# Can someone post an example of code that can induce "Governor limits" exception?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, force.com, governorlimits

I am in need of code examples(Apex and VF) which can cause governor limits because i have not come across it in my experience

Comment: There's a thousand different ways to trigger governor limits, many of them having to do with SOQL/DML in a loop. Put `for (Account a : Trigger.new) { insert new Contact(LastName='Test', AccountId = a.Id); }` in an `after insert` Account trigger and insert 200 objects; you'll get an exception right away.

Comment: @AdrianLarson  I am a learner and as i have mentioned i haven't worked on a scenario where i have encountered governor limits if not for which i wouldn't have posted it here at all. That being said i don't see a reason why this question is put on hold and by putting it on hold you are restricting my reach to the community and my learning curve.

Comment: Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. I suggest you do some research before posting here. The documentation and trailhead platform are quite thorough. This question demonstrates you want the community to help you, but not that you want to do any of the work yourself. If you post content which demonstrates such effort, it should be better received.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest governor limit to run in to is the CPU governor limit. It looks like this:

```
<apex:page controller="demoGovLimit" />
```

---

```
public class demoGovLimit {
  public demoGovLimit() {
    while(true);
  }
}
```

---

You can get lots of other governor limits simply by reading how they're triggered and then simulating that situation. Note that (*almost*) all of the governor limits are hit by running some sort of a loop, such as a DML in a loop, a query inside of a loop, recursively calling a function, and so on.

The few times when you can hit a governor limit without a loop tend to be situations where an action is restricted or prohibited in a certain context (for example, calling a future method in a batchable class).